# square of polynomial still harmonic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, harmonic-functions

Let $P(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i$ be a polynomials on $\mathbb{C}[z]$ such that $a_i$ are real numbers.

> $|P(z)|^2$ is a harmonic function ?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried any examples? Simplest example to try: $P(z)=z$.